# How can I exclude some tables when using pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-restore

I created a backup file from one database and I try to copy it to a different database, under the same schema, while excluding two large tables.

I tried this command :

```shell
pg_restore --host=violacredit.cedalsfifkcs.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
 --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=test \
 --exclude-table-data="expected_schedules" \
 --exclude-table="loan_book" \
 "C:\Users\dorc\ONEDRI~1\DOCUME~1\BACKUP~1"
```

I tried `--exclude-table-data=expected_schedules` , `--exclude-table-data='expected_schedules'` and also `--exclude-table` but I always get an error:

```
pg_restore: illegal option -- exclude-table-data=expected_schedules
pg_restore: hint: Try "pg_restore --help" for more information.
```

When trying `pg_restore --help` I can't see `--exclude-table` or `--exclude-table-data`.

How can I exclude the unwanted tables?

I'm using Postgres version 15.0

Comment: So, you are trying to use a non-existent option, and that results in an error. Why does that surprise you?

Answer (score 2):

These options exist for `pg_dump`, but not for `pg_restore`. So one thing you can do is dump the data again and use the options with `pg_dump`.

Other than that, you can create an inventory file with

```bash
pg_restore -l -f toc "C:\Users\dorc\ONEDRI~1\DOCUME~1\BACKUP~1"
```

The resulting file `toc` will look somewhat like this:

```
;
; Archive created at 2023-03-08 12:43:42 CET
;     dbname: test
;     TOC Entries: 142
;     Compression: gzip
;     Dump Version: 1.15-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;     Dumped from database version: 16devel
;     Dumped by pg_dump version: 16devel
;
;
; Selected TOC Entries:
;
225; 1259 17578 TABLE laurenz table1 laurenz
226; 1259 17581 TABLE laurenz table2 laurenz
227; 1259 17584 TABLE laurenz expected_schedules laurenz
228; 1259 17587 TABLE laurenz table3 laurenz
5637; 0 17578 TABLE DATA laurenz table1 laurenz
5638; 0 17581 TABLE DATA laurenz table2 laurenz
5639; 0 17584 TABLE DATA laurenz expected_schedules laurenz
5640; 0 17587 TABLE DATA laurenz table3 laurenz
5471; 2606 57795 CONSTRAINT laurenz table1 table1_pkey laurenz
5474; 2606 57797 CONSTRAINT laurenz table2 table2_pkey2 laurenz
5476; 2606 57799 CONSTRAINT laurenz expected_schedules expected_schedules_pkey laurenz
5478; 2606 57801 CONSTRAINT laurenz table3 table3_pkey laurenz
```

Edit the file with a text editor and remove the lines that belong to the table that you'd like to exclude. In my example, that would be the lines starting with `227`, `5638` and `5476`.

Then you can restore exactly the objects that remain in the list:

```bash
pg_restore -L toc --host=violacredit.cedalsfifkcs.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=test "C:\Users\dorc\ONEDRI~1\DOCUME~1\BACKUP~1"
```